How to set PDF flags for a pw.TextField that I want to be multiline?
I'm working with the PDF package in Flutter. I want to generate a PDF that has a text field that you can modify with multiple lines of text like this format where you can write in a specific space and have the text inside this box without overflowing. The code snippet I'm having an issue with it the following:
//textfield on a PDF.
  static pw.Widget _myTextField(String textInsideField) {
    return pw.Table(border: pw.TableBorder.all(width: 1), children: [
      pw.TableRow(children: [
        pw.Padding(
          padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.all(15),
          child: pw.TextField(
            fieldFlags: Set.from(PdfFieldFlags.multiline), <-Line of code not working.
              height: 300,
              value: textInsideField,
              name: 'My information below',
              backgroundColor: PdfColors.grey200),
        ),
      ]),
    ]);
  }

If I take out the line of code pointed with the arrow it works. However, whenever you click on the PDF to modify the field it appears as a single line of text really long line of text instead of multiple. Any help or workaround would be appreciated.
